# Non-virtual function declaration ends with =0

Tags: c++, syntax

```
string foo() const = 0;
```

What exactly does this function declaration mean? In particular, what is the '=0' good for, since the function is not declared to be virtual?

Comment: This isn't valid if `foo` isn't virtual. This line on its own doesn't prove `foo` to be nonvirtual, too.

Comment: @chris: Thanks! 'foo' isn't declared virtual anywhere else; I already suspected that it doesn't make sense since I also tried to google it but nothing came up. I don't have a compiler at the ready so I thought I'd ask here

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The =0 is the syntax that the function is a pure virtual function. As far as i know that declaration also needs to be preceeded by the keyword virtual.

More reading about this here: [What does it mean to set the declaration of a function equal to 0? How can you assign an integer to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634358/what-does-it-mean-to-set-the-declaration-of-a-function-equal-to-0-how-can-you-a)

[Difference between a virtual function and a pure virtual function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652198/difference-between-a-virtual-function-and-a-pure-virtual-function)